# Conditionally Hiding React Native InputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, react-native, inputaccessoryview

I am looking for a way to conditionally an InputAccessoryView on a React Native TextInput. I currently have an iOS button at the bottom of my screen above my nav bar but whenever my user opens an input I want said button to be pushed upwards with the keyboard. I have duplicated the button and inserted it into a `<InputAccessoryView/>` which works well.

However, when the keyboard is closed, the button falls through the bottom of the screen with the keyboard, but it doesn't look good because the duplicate buttons are visible for a split second. I am looking for a way to hide said InputAccessoryView as soon as the keyboard about to close.

I have tried conditionally rendering the InputAccessoryView based on the keyboard state, but this seems to re-render the keyboard every time. Furthermore, I have tried doing the same with the nativeID on the InputAccessoryView, but have had no success. I have also looked into using a KeyboardAvoidingView, as this is seemingly the functionality I am looking for, but had issues with it working on iOS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.